# Git: commit file with LR with msys/cygwin Git

Tags: windows, git, cygwin, newline, lf

I have a bash script under Git version control on Windows (cygwin git).

I would like checkout file from repo with LF (it is bash script) on windows (and I have core.autocrlf=true). As a result, I've got CRLF file and "$'\r': command not found" error message for script. How I could workaround this issue?

BR

Answer (score 0):

Set the `igncr` option for your bash shell.

Comment: Yes, "igncr" could help. Additional info: http://lists-archives.org/cygwin/59110-bash-igncr-and-bash_env-was-bash-igncr-documentation-where.html